# how can we display percentage symbol in textview in android

Tags: android, xml, special-characters

I am using android text view to display the constant data in manifest.XML file, I need to display the text like this 80% But now it displays 80.

Here is my text view widget can you please help to me.`

```
   <TextView
         android:text="80" />
```

Comment: Why text view in manifest.xml file?

Comment: I think you have another problem otherwise if you put "80%" text is show correctly please check carefully you are try to change text anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to display percentage in xml file then you have to use strings.xml file for that like below:

```
<string name="percent_sign">80&#x0025;</string>
```

use this string in your layout file for display percentage:

```
android:text="@string/percent_sign" />

or

android:text="80&#x0025;" />
```

instead of

```
android:text="80" />
```

Comment: where i have to use this "Percentage_sign" can you please clarify

Comment: I used android:text="@string/precentage_sign" it displays % symbol only how can i display both 80 and %, that one android:text="80&#x0025" id display only 80, it doesn't display 80%

Comment: do in your code `textView.setText(percentValue+R.string.percent_sign);`

Comment: @user3619128 you can accept my answer if its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display percentage symbol in `TextView` you just need add "%" symbol in your XML layout:

```
 android:text="80%"
```

or in your java :

```
TextView.setText("80%");
```

Comment: I tried that android:text="80%" but it still displays only 80 only in the screen

Comment: @SilentKiller I'm using this method in my application, and its work

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TextView android:text="80&#x0025;"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```